# I cannot convert SocketMessage.Content to CharArray with .ToCharArray in discord.net

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am trying to convert this message received by a Discord bot to an array of characters and I get error CS0021 "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'

Here is the method in question

```
#pragma warning disable CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
        private async Task CommandReceiver(SocketMessage messageParam)
        {
            if (messageParam.Content.ToCharArray[0] != '$') { return; }
            Console.WriteLine($"MESSAGE > {messageParam.Author} > {messageParam.Content}");

        }
#pragma warning restore CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
```

Comment: messageParam.Content.ToCharArray()[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToCharArray is a method, and requires the () when executing the method:

```
 if (messageParam.Content.ToCharArray()[0] != '$') { return; }
```